# SQL code to filter out records with a null field

Tags: sql, ms-word, mailmerge

I am trying to write code in word for a mail merge document so it opens a csv file and then It can select records which are not null for a mailing name and then it merges them so I can print them off is it possible.

```
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.DataSource.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM [Merge$] where [mailing_name]<> ''"
.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
```

it just does not like the 2nd line of this code..
any ideas on who I can contact as going around in circles????

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out `NULL` records using `Is NOT NULL` condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Merge$] 
where [mailing_name] Is NOT NULL
```

If you want to remove empty string's too in [mailing_name] column then add `or [mailing_name] <> ''`

Comment: does not work what every code I try it does not like.it I get error 5638 word could not phrase your options into a valid string...

Comment: With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.DataSource.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM [Merge$]'"
.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument    this works but has all records is there no way of filtering it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need brackets for the name of the field.

```
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .DataSource.QueryString = "SELECT * FROM [Merge$] where mailing_name<>''"
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With
```